# What Mean Should One use for CUSUM change detection?

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, change-point

I'm new to CUSUM and I'm using it to detect change of temperature over time past a certain threshold.

My data are daily temperatures from July through October, and I am using 0.5*SD for my C and 5*SD for my T (threshold). I'm looking for a drop in temperature such that S_t surpasses T.

My question is this.  For the CUSUM change detection model, should I be using the mean/SD of the entire set, or the mean/SD of some subset of the data?

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer? I can post one if the answer is yes.

Comment: Absolutely still interested.  Thanks.

Comment: In the classic CUSUM algorithm, the log likelihood ratio is summed over time and compared to a historical minimum for detecting change-points. Are you using a different CUSUM procedure?